# Создание модальных окон в расширении Google Chrome на JavaScript без JQuery

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте. Сразу убедительная просьба при ответе на вопрос - НЕ ПРЕДЛАГАТЬ JQUERY и не спрашивать почему или чем не устраивает оное.
Пишу расширение для Google Chrome, где будет функция вызывающее всплывающее окно (например как это делается с помощью JQuery UI) на заранее определенной странице сайта, хочу это сделать на чистом JS. Надо чтобы оно было модальным, и  его можно было таскать за заголовок и можно было добавлять и настраивать элементы, кнопки и т.д. на чистом JS (например appendChild). Проблема в том, что все примеры оказались не дееспособными: при инъекции выводится только текст где-то вверху или внизу страницы. На пустой странице все выводится без проблем, на странице с уже имеющимся оформлении проблема. Jquery UI выводит без проблем, но в данном вопросе религия не позволяет использовать данную библиотеку. Может кто-нибудь подсказать готовый пример скрипта вывода модального окна на JS+CSS/CSS3+HTML/HTML5, которое могло бы "перекрывать" все элементы на странице и отображалось бы также хорошо как и на JQUERY UI без использования такого.
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: @slavutich, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

**тут не форум сделайте мне! вот **ТЗ** !**

Comment: рассчитывал на ответ людей сталкивавшихся с таким при разработке расширений под хром, например: в css надо добавить то-то чтобы твое окно поверх всей странице было, или в jquery ui используется такой-то параметр css, либо ссылку, где подобные окна аналогичные jquery ui уже создавались, но без jquery. впервые слышу чтобы учащиеся решали задания по написанию расширений, ну если так надо: document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += '<div id="modWindow">...</div>', а какие параметры css должны быть, все примеры что выдавал гугл не подошли, показывало только с jquery ui.

Comment: ну в чем ваша проблема ? посмотрите как это сделано в jquery-ui или bootstrap, сделайте так-же без jquery. А просто так без либ писать ui с окошками  это мазохизм какой-то. вообще все таскание окошек основано на перехвате события mousemove между mousedown и mouseup.

Comment: проблема была в том, что зря время потратил на составление вопроса. ну, а перетаскивание окошек не такой и мазохизм, в кроссбраузерности в данном случае нет необходимости. мне нужна была подсказка с упором на css, везде делал акцент на это, никто не подсказал к сожалению (оказался z-index), а копать jquery-ui, во истину ценный совет. Наверно в след раз буду вопросы сразу писать: "подскажите я вот хочу сделать, как в jquery, но без него, мне может поискать в jquery как это делается? Нужен опытный совет, а то я новичок не знаю что можно смотреть оттуда код, вдруг кто-то здесь будет против")))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотри, я специально статью еще давно написал по поводу модальных окон: http://lampacore.ru/2013/02/18/drag-and-drop-html-javascript/

Дальше можно оперировать с ним как угодно) Тебе лишь нужно заменить обработчики событий и получение offset() на  нативный, т.е.

```
elem.offsetTop;
elem.offsetLeft;

obj.addEventListener("mousedown/mouseup/mousemove", you_function, false);
```

Comment: спс, большое, единственное пример не работает в хроме под линуксом, ругается на $, а так еще больше ясности в этом вопросе

Answer (score 0):

выкладываю исходники того, что получилось, если кому-то пригодятся:

```
окно_которое_надо_таскать.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
окно_которое_надо_таскать.onmousedown = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == "id_заголовка_окна_за_который_нужно_таскать_родителя") {
        var self = this;
        e = fixEvent(e);

        var coords = getCoords(this);
        var shiftX = e.pageX - coords.left;
        var shiftY = e.pageY - coords.top;

        this.style.position = "absolute";

        document.body.appendChild(this);
        moveAt(e);

        this.style.zIndex = 1001;

        function moveAt(e) {
            self.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + "px";
            self.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + "px"
        }

        document.onmousemove = function (e) {
            e = fixEvent(e);
            moveAt(e)

        }

        this.onmouseup = function () {
            document.onmousemove = self.onmouseup = null
        }
    }
}

окно_которое_надо_таскать.ondragstart = function () {
    return false
}

function getCoords(elem) {
    var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    var body = document.body;
    var docEl = document.documentElement;
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
    var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docEl.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;
    var clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
    var clientLeft = docEl.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;
    var top = box.top + scrollTop - clientTop;
    var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;
    return {
        top: Math.round(top),
        left: Math.round(left)
    };
}

function fixEvent(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (!e.target) e.target = e.srcElement;
    if (e.pageX == null && e.clientX != null) {
        var html = document.documentElement;
        var body = document.body;
        e.pageX = e.clientX + (html.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0);
        e.pageX -= html.clientLeft || 0;
        e.pageY = e.clientY + (html.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0);
        e.pageY -= html.clientTop || 0
    }

    if (!e.which && e.button) e.which = e.button & 1 ? 1 : e.button & 2 ? 3 : e.button & 4 ? 2 : 0;
    return e;
}
```